# Looking for a short story with airstream globetrotters and a boy having Down syndrome

Tags: story-identification, alien-invasion

I am searching for a science fiction story I read years ago (I guess around 2000). I was part of an SF-Short-Story-Collection (Isaac Asimov's Magazine or the  Heyne-Almanach [[example]](https://www.randomhouse.de/ebook/Das-Science-Fiction-Jahr-2014/Sascha-Mamczak/Heyne/e465473.rhd)) and was published translated in German in Germany.
The story is about an alien invasion. The strange thing is that the aliens love the [airstream globetrotter (the silver Caravan)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airstream) - they are really mad about them.

Another Thing I remember is that the only people which can communicate with the Aliens suffer from  [trisomy 21 (Down Syndrome)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Down_syndrome).

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site, including tips on story identification questions.

Comment: @Politank-Z The tour doesn't say anything specifically about story-ID questions. A better link to point to might be [How to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31394). Lars, if you read through the checklists included in that link, they might help to jog your memory for extra details you didn't know you remembered. Once again, welcome, and I hope you find the story you're looking for :-)